# passing parameter from $.ajax post to mysqli_query not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass parameter from $.ajax post to mysqli_query

this is my ajax

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'edit-doctor.php',
       data: "imei="+imei,        
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
                    $.each(data, function() {
             $.each(this, function(k , v) {
             trHTML += '<tr><td><b>'+ k.toString() + '</b></td> : <td>' + v.toString() + '</td></tr>';

        })        
        })

        $("#target_table_id").append(trHTML);
    }
    });
```

this is my php

```
<?php 

include("connect.php");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$src1= $_POST["imei"];  //.. getting variable in src1

      $sql = "select * from tbl_beacons where imei =  '".$src1."' ";

//$sql = "select * from tbl_beacons where imei =  '".$_POST['imei']."' ";
// also tried this 

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

$conn->close();
```

problem is that I am able to get parameter but not able to pass in query and get result . if i send hardcore value then query is working fine

what I can modify to get parameter value and send it

EDIT:

i also figured out and modfied ajax , this also working

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "edit-doctor.php",
            data: {imei:imei},
            success: function (data) {
                    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function() {
             $.each(this, function(k , v) {
             trHTML += '<tr><td><b>'+ k.toString() + '</b></td> : <td>' + v.toString() + '</td></tr>';

        })        
        })
        $("#target_table_id").append(trHTML);
        }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. data: "imei="+imei,       is not JSON. Try  `data: {imei:imei},`
2. if you send JSON you need to receive JSON too
3. You can also just remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",`

Even better:

```
$.post('edit-doctor.php', {"imei":imei},function (data) {
  var trHTML=[]; 
  $.each(data, function() {
    $.each(this, function(k , v) {
      trHTML.push('<tr><td><b>'+ k + '</b></td> : <td>' + v + '</td></tr>');
    })        
  })
  $("#target_table_id").append(trHTML.join(''));
});
```

Comment: i considered this as my answer , thanx

Comment: this is the most easy way to send data from js to php , but this way not powerful enough ,if u write somethg big / powerful / user friendly

Comment: @J.WCT - what does that mean, not powerful enough? If you mean there is no error handling then just use the original $.ajax